# JS Arrow fuinction returns self not function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In React I'm using utility functions to handle the api calls. When the Arrow function is no longer anonymous it returns a pending promise, which is what I would like. However when the arrow function is anonymous it returns the function.

Is there any way to return a pending promise in one line?

Here is what the function looks like when not anonymous:

```js
const list = () => {
    let res = async () => await api.get("list");
    return res();
}
```

Here is what it looks like anonymous:

```js
const list = () => {
    return async () => await api.get("list")
}
```

Comment: Why not `return api.get("list")`?

Comment: In your first example you're invoking the function on return, which is different from your second example where you're just returning the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're just returning the function, not executing it.  This *executes* the function:

```
res();
```

Nowhere in the second example do you have that additional set of parentheses to execute it.  Add them:

```
const list = () => {
  return (async () => await api.get("list"))();
}
```

Or, [even simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74308683/js-arrow-fuinction-returns-self-not-function/74308713#comment131188574_74308683), don't wrap the operation in an unnecessary function in the first place:

```
const list = () => {
  return api.get("list");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, will accept this as the answer

Comment: Note, there is zero reason for this `return (async () => await api.get("list"))();`.  Just use `return api.get("list");` (as shown in the second example).  Both just return a promise that resolves with the result of the api call so go with the simpler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With your second example you are returning a function, not the result of the function. Store the function in an object and call the function:

```js
const list = () => {
    return (async () => await api.get("list"))();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the function res in the second case, not the output of res. You can use an IIFE to return the value of res as wanted:

```js
const list = () => {
    return api.get("list")
}
```